# How scaling element of shape in inkscape?

Tags: graphics, inkscape

How make a smaller ring and not scaling every inside element?

[image: example]

From circle i delete holes (lilie) how make smalest outside ring and not scale holes inside?

Comment: this is not scaling but cutting ...

Answer (score 1):

You could [clip](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clipping-and-masking.html) it.

> [...] put the object that will serve as clip (or mask) above the
> object that you want to clip (or mask). Then select both objects, and
> use **Object ‣ Clip ‣ Set** or Object ‣ Mask ‣ Set. The top object
> will then become invisible and work to hide parts of the bottom
> object.

So for your case you would make a circle and select the inner region and the circle. The circle needs to be on top.

Comment: this is not resize (bezier tie or other way) only crop ;-)

Comment: if the outline is not a circle is problem.